# Flutter DevTools network missing requests

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using DevTools to inspect network, I figured out that it not shown all requests, I am sure that I clear filters and it must show all requests, but when my app send multiple request in sub-second, network inspection only shows some of them not all

Where is problem?

Comment: I have this issue too. It is very frustrating.

Comment: hey guys, any luck with this.
I'm new in flutter and facing same.